# What is the Riemann curvature tensor contracted with the metric tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, tensor-calculus

Can the [Ricci curvature tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature) be obtained by a 'double contraction' of the Riemann curvature tensor? For example

$R_{\mu\nu}=g^{\sigma\rho}R_{\sigma\mu\rho\nu}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'double contraction', but the Ricci tensor in local coordinates is given by
\begin{align}
R_{\mu \nu} = R^\rho_{~~\mu \rho \nu},
\end{align}
which is the same as $g^{\sigma \rho} R_{\sigma \mu \rho \nu}$, exactly what you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The expression for the Ricci tensor is often written as ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature))
$$
  R_{\mu\nu} = R^{\alpha}_{\phantom\alpha \mu\alpha\nu},
$$
but the right hand side is precisely what you wrote since the metric simply raises the first index.

Comment: Woops sorry I hadn't seen @nervxxx's answer when I wrote mine.

Comment: You still get +1 from me anyway. Also, since we know that $R_{\mu\nu}=R_{\nu\mu}$, would it be true to say that we can swap the first and third indices in the Riemann tensor, even if they're all downstairs?

Comment: Yup! Just FYI there are a bunch of identities here that are pretty useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor